# excel worksheet range / prevsheet

Tags: microsoft-excel, range

very much a beginner to excel...

i need to get a cells value **J1** from the first worksheet of the month named **2018-04-01** through to the lastest worksheet **2018-04-25**

am able to do that no problem using below formula

`=SUM('2018-04-01:2018-04-25'!J1)`

however, each day I have to create a new worksheet that increments by one day in this format(year-month-day) aka **2018-04-25**

thats fine, I do that manually and move it to the right of the previous day **2018-04-24** so visually the tabs looks like this
`... | 2018-04-24 | 2018-04-25 | april |`

in my **april** worksheet - where I run the very first formula I posted - I have several instances of the formula that use the same worksheet range, but reference different cells

e.g.

- `=SUM('2018-04-01:2018-04-25'!J1)`
- `=SUM('2018-04-01:2018-04-25'!C1)`
- `=SUM('2018-04-01:2018-04-25'!A1)`

to get various totals for each day into the month worksheet

but I have to go into each cell on the month worksheet after creating a new daily worksheet and change the last date in the range **2018-04-25** to the current day

what I am ideally wanting to do is as below

in my **april** worksheet;
instead of this
`=SUM('2018-04-01:2018-04-25'!J1)`

something like this 
`=SUM('2018-04-01:PrevSheet()'!J1)`

*(which i am hoping should automatically reference the latest worksheet and update all of the formulas in the april workbook to save manually altering them)*

so mixing a literal worksheet name with a kind of variable

have spent MANY hours trying examples on the internet but nothing close so far

p.s. i have also added the **=PrevSheet** formula to a cell in my **april** worksheet **cell M1** which returns the text **2018-04-25** which i then tried to reference in that first formula **eg** `=SUM('2018-04-01:M1'!J1)` , but still no dice

any help would be gratefully received

**Edit:** have added screenshots as requested

original formula:
[image: original formula]

new suggested formula:
[image: new suggested formula]

Answer (score 0):

You're close, just need to add [`INDIRECT()`](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/indirect-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) function:

```
=SUM(INDIRECT("'2018-04-01:" & M1 & "'!J1"))
```

Comment: Máté, thanks so much for the answer, upon trying that i get #REF! instead of the expected cell result. maybe you can't mix a literal worksheet name(2018-04-01) with a cell that is general text in cell M1 derived from =prevsheet in one range formula?

Comment: please evaluate your formula (formulas - evaluate) and see how Excel understands it. Hopefully that will help. If not, then please update your question with a screenshot of the formula.

Comment: i tried to evaluate the formula and it did  return M1 as being 2018-04-28 which looks correct, but other than that am not sure how to further use that tool. have included screenshot links as requested, thanks a lot.

Comment: *mistake in above comment, meant 2018-04-25

Comment: Your links doesn't seem to work:(

Comment: sry about that, they work fine here, have added another set to the bottom of the post anyway - i don't know my way proficiently round this site yet - apologies!